# How do I set values to view in MarkerInfoWindow?

Tags: android, osmdroid

I use the OSMBonusPack library for creating markers on map. From this library, I use `MarkerInfoWindow`. I extended my own class `CustomInfoWindow` from `MarkerInfoWindow`. Then I try to set values for view-elements (`tvDescribe` and `bubbleImage`), that is contained in the layout of the `InfoWindow`, but a `NullPointerException` from it appears:

```
public class CustomInfoWindow extends MarkerInfoWindow {
    TextView tvDescribe; //Description of point in infoWindow
    ImageView bubbleImage;//Image in infoWindow
    View view;

public CustomInfoWindow(MapView mapView, Drawable markerImage, String description) {
            super(R.layout.my_layout, mapView);//my_layout is layout for InfoWindow
            view = mapView;
            tvDescribe = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bubble_description);
            bubbleImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.bubble_image);
            tvDescribe.setText(description);
            bubbleImage.setImageDrawable(markerImage);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should be use **onOpen()** method:

```
    TextView tvDescribe; //Description of point in infoWindow
    ImageView bubbleImage;//Image in infoWindow

    Drawable markerImage;
    String description;


    public CustomInfoWindow(MapView mapView, Drawable markerImage, String description) {
        super(R.layout.my_layout, mapView);//my_layout is layout for InfoWindow

        this.markerImage = markerImage;
        this.description = description;

    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(Object item) {
        super.onOpen(item);

        tvDescribe = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.bubble_description);
        bubbleImage = (ImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.bubble_image);
        tvDescribe.setText(description);
        bubbleImage.setImageDrawable(markerImage);
    }
```